# Scope limits @Async in Spring

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

Hi i was reading about `Async` annotation support in Spring.

I have a doubt in mind and that is

Is there any scope limitation while using Async annotation?

Suppose

there are 2 methods `m1()` and `m2()`
`m2()` is Async in nature and called from `m1()`

if `m1()` takes 5 mins for execution and `m2()` takes 15 mins, what will be the behavior?

will I get output after 5 mins? or `m1()` will wait till `m2()` gets executed?

I understand that `Async` will make `m2()` execute in different thread but just not sure regarding above scenario

Comment: spring creates an executor for this. m1 will finish after 5 minutes and before it finishes m2 will be spanned. But m1 is not going to wait around for m2 to finish, if that is what you want. That's the idea of using async

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you will have results when the callback method (if, indeed, there is a callback method) is executed after m2() has completed.  When m1() completes, there is no result to inspect yet.  The answer is 15 minutes plus however long it took for m1() to invoke m2().

If m1() is not dependent on the result of m2(), then you should have your output when m1() completes, but that doesn't mean the thread running the m2() invocation has completed.

Comment: are you sure? can you give me any reference to such statements, as i am still trying to get one, if not found, will need to implement and check

Comment: :-| Yes.  If the data/resource you need is generated by m2(), how could you *possibly* get that data/resource *before* m2() has finished executing?  m1() will exit and some listener or observer or something must be awaiting the results of m2() to act on them.

Comment: lets say m2 is void and we expect nothing out of it! then?

Comment: If m1() doesn't depend on the result of m2() in any way, then you'll have everything you need when m1() completes.

Comment: You might want to try illustrating an example for yourself.  You might be able to figure this out on your own.  :-)